# The difference between ~(x-1) and ~x+1 when x=0x80000000

Tags: c, bit-shift

The language I use is C.
The type of x and n is int.

I have one line code as following

```
  printf("x=%x,n=%d,first=%x,second=%x\n",x,n,((~(x+0xffffffff))>>n),((~x+1)>>n));
```

It shows the value of x,n and two methods of shifting n bits of the complement number of x.
When x=0x80000000,~(x+0xffffffff)=0x8000000,~x+1=0x80000000, yet when shift these two by n bits, the results are different.

btw, if I changed 0xffffffff to ~1+1(that means ~(x+(~1+1)), the result is the same as ~x+1

I wonder why that happened. Thanks.

Comment: [Is “(uint16_t) -1″ Portable C Code?](http://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2011/06/is-uint16_t-1-portable-c-code/)

Comment: @Lundin That article is wrong. `(uint16_t)-1` **is** guaranteed by the standard to produce `0xFFFF` if the implementation provides that type in `stdint.h`. (Of course, nothing is guaranteed if it's your own typedef.) There's no ambiguity, the fixed-width types are required to have no padding bits, so it isn't even restricted to the value bits (well, it is, since there are only value bits in `uintN_t`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The now deleted answer by Pavan Manjunath had the correct answer for one case, assuming that `int` is as usual a 32-bit type. The integer constant

```
0xffffffff
```

has the value `2^32 - 1` and that isn't representable by an `int`, but it is representable as an `unsigned int`. So its type is `unsigned int` (6.4.4.1). Hence `x` is converted to `unsigned int` for the addition, and

```
((~(x+0xffffffff))>>n)
```

evaluates as

```
((~(0x80000000u + 0xffffffffu)) >> n)
((~0x7fffffffu) >> n)
(0x80000000u >> n)
```

with the value `2^(31-n)` if `0 <= n < 32` (it's undefined behaviour if `n` is outside that range).

For the other case, ouah's answer is correct, when `x = 0x80000000` is an `int`, `~0x8000000 = 0x7fffffff = INT_MAX` and `INT_MAX + 1` is undefined behaviour as signed integer overflow.

Nevertheless, a common behaviour is wrap-around, and then the result of the addition is the signed integer `0x80000000` and right-shifting of negative integers is implementation-defined behaviour (6.5.7). Common is shifting with sign-extension, which would yield the result `-2^(31-n)`, which then is interpreted as the `unsigned int` with the value `2^32 - 2^(31-n)` by the `printf` conversion specifier `%x`.

Comment: `0` is representable as an `int`, so the type of `~0` is `int` too.

Answer (score 1):

> When x=0x80000000,~(x+0xffffffff)=0x8000000,~x+1=0x80000000,

On a system with 32-bit `int` (assuming `x` is of type `int`) and two's complement signed representation, this expression:

```
 ~x+1
```

is undefined behavior. `x = 0x80000000` means `~x == 0x7FFFFFFF == INT_MAX` and `INT_MAX + 1` is undefined behavior. So `~x + 1` can be `0x80000000` or anything else.

This expression:

```
~(x+0xffffffff)
```

on the other hand is defined (`0xffffffff` is `unsigned int` in C) and is equal to `0x80000000`. It is actually defined because `0xffffffff` is `unsigned int` and unsigned integers never overflow in the sense of the C standard.

This means that this statement:

```
printf("x=%x,n=%d,first=%x,second=%x\n",x,n,((~(x+0xffffffff))>>n),((~x+1)>>n));
```

invokes undefined behavior and it makes no sense to compare both results.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming sizeof(int) is 4; i.e., 32 bit signed value).
0x80000000;    // -2147483648 which is smallest possible negative int
0xFFFFFFFF         // is -1

Adding the two together causes a 'wrap around' from negative to positive
0x7FFFFFFF    is the sum of the two (using int arithmetic), which is 2147483647

Using the '~' operator on 0x7FFFFFFF yields a bit-wise completent, or 0x80000000

If you start with any int value and subtract 1 from it (or add 1 to it, it doesn't matter) enough times, you will cause it to flip its sign. This is a basic problem with arithmetic using a fixed precision.

In your case, you can't expect to mix signed arithmetic and bitwise operators without being very mindful of this limiting case.

Also note that there is an asymmetry when using 2's complement arithmetic: there is one more negative number than positive (because you need to represent zero, which leaves an odd number of other bit representations for the rest of the values.)